# LSM Automatic Module Invocation

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module

How can the LSM be used to automatically invoke custom written kernel modules?

Specifically I would like for my module to be called every time a new process is instantiated so that it can do some checking on the SELinux labels -> if there is a better way (scheduler modification?) to do this let me know.

I am trying to avoid constantly polling the process list every X ms.

Comment: I think this will answer you question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10428212/how-can-i-implement-my-own-hook-function-with-lsm