# How can I implement my own hook function with LSM?

Tags: linux-kernel

I'm learning something about access control.
And try to implement own hook function with LSM api.
But I found I have to code in the kernel source in Kernel version 3.1.4.
So , how can I get started?

Could someone give an example about it?
Thanks a lot.

PS: I have found some examples, but in kernel version 2.6.20. As LSM have been modified, those examples cannot work.

Answer (score 1):

You can't load an LSM module since 2.6.35 (see c1e992b99603a84d7debb188542b64f2d9232c07 commit). So, it isn't a valid task to get LSM outside the kernel. But you always can try to disassemble the kernel at run time and find all the private symbols such as [security_ops](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.3.4/security/security.c#L29) pointer.

For example, have a look at the exported `security_sb_copy_data` symbol:

```
int security_sb_copy_data(char *orig, char *copy)
{
        return security_ops->sb_copy_data(orig, copy);
}
EXPORT_SYMBOL(security_sb_copy_data);
```

It dump may looks this (x86_64):

```
(gdb) x/7i security_sb_copy_data 
   0xffffffff811f61b0:  push   %rbp
   0xffffffff811f61b1:  mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0xffffffff811f61b4:  data32 data32 data32 xchg %ax,%ax
   0xffffffff811f61b9:  mov    0x881690(%rip),%rax        # 0xffffffff81a77850
   0xffffffff811f61c0:  callq  *0x98(%rax)
   0xffffffff811f61c6:  pop    %rbp
   0xffffffff811f61c7:  retq
```

So, the `0xffffffff81a77850` address is the exact `security_ops` pointer. Let's check it out with:

```
(gdb) x/s* 0xffffffff81a77850
0xffffffff81850fa0:  "default"
```

OK, now we have valid `security_ops` pointer and can do anything with LSM outside the kernel.

`P.S.` There is a great Linux kernel security project - AKARI. It implements interesting methods of private symbols resolution without disassembly (see [sources](http://akari.sourceforge.jp/1.0/chapter-3.html.en) for details).

Comment: Thanks a lot~ I found AKARI is based on Tomoyo? OK, I'll have a try.