# Make a minifilter like driver for linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, fanotify

I'm new to the Linux file system. I wanted to use a mini filter like the driver for Linux, I came across various options like Hooks,DazukoFS(not used nowadays) fanotify. So I chose fanotify.
I want to modify a file before opening it. The similar work is performed by antiviruses they scan each file before opening.I'm not getting any method to do this task. Even not getting any proper documentation of fanotify using which I will be able to achieve this. I came across FAN_OPEN_PERM, again there was no example. Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The Linux kernel architecture does not lend itself to layering and add-on services. There is no concept of filter and miniport drivers. I don't believe that has changed in more recent kernels. It will probably be difficult to impossible for you.

Comment: But I think hooks does the job of providing add-on services.    
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15739320/hook-functions-for-linux-filesystem